I can not import PLSRegression with the code "from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression."
I am trying to import PLSregression as from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression, PLSSVD.
But I am encountering this error: cannot import name 'pinv2' from 'scipy.linalg.
Even though I updated everything, I couldn't fix it. Can anybody please help me?
I updated the last versions of scikit-learn and scipy.

This question is similar to: cannot import name 'pinv2' from 'scipy.linalg'. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
